# How to solve this integral with two pole point and imaginary unit i?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

There is a integral, when $m+n$ is odd $$ \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} {\rm d}t \ \frac{ \left\{1-(-1)^{n}\exp[-it]\right\} \left\{1-(-1)^{m}\exp[it]\right\} }{(t^{2}-n^{2}\pi^{2})(t^{2}-m^{2}\pi^{2})}t = \frac{4i}{(n^{2}-m^{2})\pi}$$
and when $n+m$ is even
$$ \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} {\rm d}t \ \frac{ \left\{1-(-1)^{n}\exp[-it]\right\} \left\{1-(-1)^{m}\exp[it]\right\} }{(t^{2}-n^{2}\pi^{2})(t^{2}-m^{2}\pi^{2})}t = 0$$
I don't know how to prove this integral and the answer may not right.
Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Difficult. This is a very good problem.  I would try first $n=0$ and $m=1.$

Comment: When $n+m$ is even, the integrand is an odd function (using Euler's formula), so the principle value is zero. When $n+m$ is odd, the integrand reduces to $\pm\frac{t\sin(t)}{(t^2-n^2\pi^2)(t^2-m^2\pi^2)}$, which may be evaluated by contour integration of the related integral $\frac{e^{iat}}{(t^2-n^2\pi^2)(t^2-m^2\pi^2)}$. The result is $\frac{2i(\cos(n\pi)-\cos(m\pi))}{\pi(n^2-m^2)}$. I suggest you add context and your attempts to avoid having your question closed